# Compare timestamp in java with mongoDB timestamp to fetch range of values

Tags: java, mongodb

As i have found multiple answers to this question, I am not convinced after trying them, so want to discuss again. Here's my DB:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("58510deae17ee5fc404a6f38"),
    "Interface_Name" : "SDE-CONTROLLER",
    "MsgCount" : "9798",
    "SubsystemType" : 2,
    "Mean" : "1224750",
    "Dest" : "CDN",
    "DataCenterId" : "d1@ssipl",
    "SRC" : "SDE",
    "peakMsgTimestamp" : "1481706908",
    "PeakMsgCount" : "3087",
    "SuccessMsgBytes" : "137172",
     "VmId" : "vm1",
    "TIMESTAMP" : ISODate("2016-12-14T09:16:26.459Z")
```

}

My java code is :

```
    long startTime = 0,endTime =0;
    Date startDateObj = new Date();
    Date endDateObj = new Date();
    MongoDatabase mongoDb = MongoDBUtil.getInstance().getDB();
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDb.getCollection(table);
    String startDate = voAppDto.getStartDate();
    String endDate = voAppDto.getEndDate();
    if (startDate.length() > 0) {
        calendarFrom.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(startDate.split("-")[0]));
        calendarFrom.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(startDate.split("-")[1]) - 1);
        calendarFrom.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(startDate.split("-")[2].substring(0, 2)));
        startTime = calendarFrom.getTimeInMillis();
        startDateObj.setTime(startTime);
    }
    if (endDate.length() > 0) {
        calendarTo.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(endDate.split("-")[0]));
        calendarTo.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.parseInt(endDate.split("-")[1]) - 1);
        calendarTo.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(endDate.split("-")[2].substring(0, 2)));
        endTime = calendarTo.getTimeInMillis();
        endDateObj.setTime(endTime);
    }
   MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(and(eq("Interface_Name","SDE-CONTROLLER"),eq("DataCenterId","d1@ssipl"),lt("TIMESTAMP",endDateObj),gt("TIMESTAMP",startDateObj))).iterator();
```

I am able to get records but no. of of records mismatch while executing same query in mongoDB.

Comment: What is your java version ?

Comment: My java version is Java 8

Comment: What is the format for endDate and startDate ?

Comment: startDate = 2016-01-01 00:00:00  ,endDate = 2017-01-01 00:00:00